# How to connect to the exchange 2013 EWS via php (just get photo)

Tags: php, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

How to connect to the exchange 2013 EWS just get photo ?
What Library do I need (API) and how to embed it ? (I 'm beginner in php)

Here's a code I have now:

```
https://exchange.domen.local/ews/exchange.asmx/s/GetUserPhoto?email=mail@mail.ru&size=HR240x240
```

He ask me login/password. That's good. But I need a way to write the Login/password to the script. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I handled this in PHP using curl. It is simple with no dependencies outside of curl.

Tested against an Exchange 2013 server. Saves to a file directly.

```
$server = ''; // owa.whatever.com, etc.
$user = ''; // username without domain info
$password = '';
$email_to_get = ''; // Email to pull photo
$fullurl = "https://$server/ews/Exchange.asmx/s/GetUserPhoto?email=$email_to_get&size=HR648x648"; //sizes defined at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj194329(v=exchg.80).aspx
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $fullurl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_NTLM | CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$user:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
$returned = curl_exec($ch);

$fp = fopen("pic.jpg", 'w'); // Save picture locally to .jpg
fwrite($fp, $returned);
fclose($fp);

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
echo $returned; // Display the image on the page if desired
```

Comment: Hello Greg. Great script, but I have a question - Does your script open photo here or it necessary extract photo from some variable. I changed variables as you told: $server="bagira.bam.loc", $user="user", $password="password",  $email_to_get="user@bsmuk.ru" (plus added two semicolon in the beginning) but nothing going on (no errors in the script) the script something does but I can't understand :).

Comment: Ah, I overlooked some semi-colons when I removed my info. I'll fix that in the post.

Comment: Oleg, the picture data is returned in $returned - that's why I write it to the file with fwrite. If you were to do a print_r($returned); you would see the binary data (and hopefully a JFIF for JPGs in the first few entries) if you go to the webpage itself. I changed fopen to use w instead of x, as w will overwrite/create the file and x only creates the file.

Comment: It occurred to me that my code downloads the picture to a file but you wish to embed it, as such, take a look at my edit that puts a JPEG header into the returned webpage and then echos the picture data. Now you get the picture versus the binary data.

Comment: It works! Cooool. You are the first in internet who realized (in detail) a simple way to get photo from Exchange. +100 ^)

Answer (score 0):

Your "Code" you provide is incomplete. You only trigger the URL but do not specify that you wish to fetch the picture from the xml stream.

The best way is to check the Microsoft HowTo [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj190905(v=exchg.150).aspx), it provides examples you could adjust to your needs. If you are unable to do that you might wish to check the PHP EWS library from [here](https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews).

Comment: The clue "xml stream" - that I need. I didn't know about ews as xml stream :). thanks. Later I 'll give the solution.